# IE11 flex item overflow vertically

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm aware of there are many flex item overflow in IE questions here, however I couldn't find the solution for the vertically overflow answer.

If you run in Chrome, you will see the content scroll vertically with an internal scroll, it respect the `max-height` of the parent. (expected)

However if you run in IE 11, it overflows instead of creating an internal scroll.

any idea?

Edit: A little of context, I'm trying to create a modal where the dialog has auto height and grow until the max-height then set internal scroll in body. something similar to https://material-ui.com/demos/dialogs/#scrolling-long-content. (scroll = paper)

Not sure how they made IE works

```css
.container {
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: blue;
}

.body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">aa</div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="content">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">ccc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: set a max-height or height on the .body

Comment: can you explain set height to what? the header/footer can have different height, I just want body to fill, that's why I use flex:1 1 auto;

Comment: because the class body is what the overflow is on that is what the ie browser needs a height specification on, maybe you need to play around with this and find a compromise, because ie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);` to `.body` (I assume header + footer = 50px).

```css
.container {
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: blue;
}

.body {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">aa</div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="content">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">ccc</div>
</div>
```

Another way is set `height: 100%` to `.container` (I'm not sure why it works well when I create html file and run in IE, but not work in html snippet here)

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: blue;
}

.body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">aa</div>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="content">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">ccc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I updated a little bit the context of what I m trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @Yichaoz, did you try my second solution? (not sure why it not work directly in SO snippet, but it works well when I create html file and run in browser), I think it might help

Comment: Setting 100% will force small dialog to be 100 height of the screen 

Comment: your first solution helped me, I also posted my final solution here

Answer (score 0):

After playing a little bit,

I just needed to add
`overflow-y: auto;` to `.container`

I created another example if someone is interest at:

https://codepen.io/kossel-the-styleful/pen/OaaPyq